# Как записать в двумерный массив

Tags: java

Есть документ с данными

```
Кредит:12500:1:
А что вы тут смотрите?:99999999:2:
Это надо закрыть:15428:3:
Люблю java:4850:4:
Долг Лехе:100050:5:
На отдых:2000:6:
```

Он читается с помощью кода

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        goInfo();
    }

    public static void goInfo() {
        try {
            try {
                File file = new File("src/BankAccount.txt");
                //создаем объект FileReader для объекта File
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                //создаем BufferedReader с существующего FileReader для построчного считывания
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
                // считаем сначала первую строку
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    // считываем остальные строки в цикле
                    line = reader.readLine();

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Как эти обработать через split() и все это записать в двумерный массив, что бы он выглядел так

```
[0][0]Кредит                   [0][1]12500       [0][2]1
[1][0]А что вы тут смотрите?   [1][1]99999999    [1][2]2
[2][0]Это надо закрыть         [2][1]15428       [2][2]3
[3][0]Люблю java:              [3][1]4850        [3][2]4
[4][0]Долг Лехе:               [4][1]100050      [4][2]5
[5][0]На отдых:                [5][1]2000        [5][2]6
```

Comment: этого делать не надо в принципе, смотрите мой ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос. все это не будет работать нормально. например, я добавил в текстовый файл такую строку: Кредит:отдавать не собираюсь:100000:7: и подобные проблемы будут возникать постоянно

Answer (score 1):

Ну как то так:

```
public static void goInfo() {
        try {
            int j = 0;

            File file = new File("src/BankAccount.txt");
            //создаем объект FileReader для объекта File
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            //создаем BufferedReader с существующего FileReader для построчного считывания
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            // считаем сначала первую строку
            for (int i = 0; i < strLeight(); i++) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                for (String retval : line.split(":")) {
                    massInfo[i][j] = retval;
                    System.out.println(massInfo[i][j]);
                    j++;
                    if (j == 3){
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```